# TCP RST does not notify application

Tags: tcp

I have A and B node exchanging data through TCP. After A establishes a connection to B and send, receive data with B. Both nodes then go to idle around 30 minutes, then B closes the connection actively. In the wireshark log, it shows that B sends [FIN,ACK] to A with the SEQ number smaller than the last package B sends to A in 30 minutes ago ( I am not sure why this happens). A responses by sending a TCP RST for this strange SEQ package from B to terminate the connection. B looks like terminate the connection sucessfully, however the TCP application from A still sends data to this connection after sending TCP RST.

My question is why TCP app from A still sends data to the current connection after seding TCP RST to terminate this connection? As TCP spec says that RST should terminate connection right away on both nodes. Does TCP stack on A notify the application that the connection is aborted? Both nodes run Linux kernel.

Comment: I suggest you've misread the Wireshark log.

Comment: Why do you think so?

Comment: Because, as you said yourself, it is all wrong. It is all in violation of RFC 793. What is the *actual* problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: That's reason why I ask :). After sending the RST, will Linux TCP stack notify the application to avoid continue sending the data? It actually sends in my tcpdump.